# Testing for bits on numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to do some bitstream parsing using Python & numpy.  It seems to be not that straightforward, as the bitwise and doesn't seem to work with numpy bytes (uint8).

What am I missing here..?

```
import bitstring
import numpy

byteform = b"\x56"
bitarray = bitstring.BitArray(byteform)
numbyte = numpy.uint8(56)
pyint = 56

bitarray.bin
# that gives '01010110'
#                  ^^^
# I want to test for these bits

# this one is the only one that works:
byteform[0] & 1 # 0 => ok
byteform[0] & 2 # 2 => ok
byteform[0] & 4 # 4 => ok
# why do I need that [0] ?

# this does not work at all.. why?
numbyte & 1 # 0
numbyte & 2 # 0
numbyte & 4 # 0

# no luck with this one either:
numpy.bitwise_and(numbyte, numpy.uint8(1))
numpy.bitwise_and(numbyte, numpy.uint8(2))
numpy.bitwise_and(numbyte, numpy.uint8(4))

# this shouldnt give the expected results since the bits are in the other end of the bytearray (it's small endian):
pyint & 1
pyint & 2
pyint & 4
```

In numpy.uint8, are there some sneaky extra bits..?  Help!

Answer (score 1):

Byteform actually isn't working, and you should realize this isn't working if you serialize the representation:

```
>>> print("{:08b}".format(56))
00111000
```

So, we only expect the lower 3 bits and upper 2 bits to be set. Your value is not 56 in the byteform, it's the hex value of 0x56, which is 86. Only 8, 16, and 32 should be the valid bits in your equation, and NumPy works just fine.

```
>>> print(byteform[0])
86
>>> print(0x56)
86
```

If you want to convert a number to binary, you can use `numpy.tobytes` or `int.to_bytes`.

```
>>> np.uint8(56).tobytes()
b'8'
>>> int.to_bytes(56, length=1, byteorder='little', signed=False)
b'8'
```

The notation for defining a byte '\xNN' does not use decimal numbers for that `NN`, it uses hexadecimal numbers, so `0xNN` produces a byte with a numerical value equivalent to `0xNN`.

## A Warning

With NumPy, and larger numbers, I do recommend actually only doing bitwise operations between NumPy integers.

```
>>> SIGN_MASK = np.uint64(0x8000000000000000) 
>>> INFINITY_BITS = np.uint64(0x7FF0000000000000)                          
>>> SIGN_MASK | INFINITY_BITS                                              
18442240474082181120
>>> SIGN_MASK | int(INFINITY_BITS)
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_or' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

This is because for larger numbers, NumPy isn't sure if the number should be signed or unsigned and therefore cannot determine the actual bitwise representation.

Comment: where did I get that idea of "\x56" being 8-bit byte value..!?   Thanks for clearing my fuzzy head.

Comment: I've tried to add an explanation down below, it's a "byte" but a byte as in a byte string using a hexadecimal literal.